# How to rotate languages link based on user selection in webpage using PHP?

Tags: php

In my page I have 3 languages, A, B and C.

When A language is active, then the below must be shown.

```
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="A">A</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>
            <a href="B">B</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="C">C</a>
        <li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

On the other hand, if for example B language is active, it should change like this:

```
<li class="has-dropdown">
    <a href="B">B</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>
            <a href="A">A</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="C">C</a>
        <li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

It doesn't really matter if A is before C, but it should be nicer to be.

How can I achieve this rotation using PHP?

Comment: `if` statements and a `loop`

Comment: @cmorrissey can you provide me an example please?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve that. One that comes to mind would be to keep the values in array:

```
$array = array("A", "B", "C");
```

Now you can order the array anyway you'd like and find the element in it that is selected. Remove it and the display it up top:

```
$selected = "B"; //figure out how to do that in the context of your code
unset($array[$selected]);
//now display B
display_link($selected);
display_list($array);
```

Where `display` functions would create your HTML elements.